# OpenVPN/iptables: Routing of Multi-Client-Side local networks

Tags: networking, iptables, routing, openvpn

We set up two open VPN instances on a cloud server:

```
6: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    inet 10.230.0.1 peer 10.230.0.2/32 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: tun1: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    inet 10.30.0.1 peer 10.30.0.2/32 scope global tun1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`tun0` is used as "Service VPN".
`tun1` is used as "Client VPN".

We do not want to use `client-to-client` in both VPN instances.

For this we have set up an IP tables rule. so that packets can be forwarded from the service VPN to the client VPN:

```
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  10.230.0.0/24        anywhere
```

We can ping any client IP from the service VPN:

```
traceroute to 10.30.0.10 (10.30.0.10), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.230.0.1 (10.230.0.1)  22.226 ms  22.152 ms  22.135 ms
 2  10.30.0.10 (10.30.0.10)  42.465 ms  42.473 ms  42.462 ms
```

There are other local networks behind the client VPN:

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 192.168.0.10/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
     inet 10.30.0.10 peer 10.30.0.9/32 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

We would like to route this network to the machine which is connected through the service VPN. In this example the network should be 192.168.0.0/24.
However, we need to ensure that multiple identical local networks from different client VPNs can be routed to different service VPNs at the same time.

We tried to solve the problem with iptables:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 10.230.0.10 -i tun0 -d 192.168.0.0/24 -j DNAT --to 10.30.0.10
```

However, all traffic is now redirected to the client VPN.
However, we need forwarding to the LAN behind it.

We have two other approaches to solve the problem:

1. use `tap` instead of `tun`.
   We don't want to do this because we want the VPNs to be separated.
2. reverse VPN
   Another VPN server on the Client-VPN device. This could provide a second OpenVPN instance as a server. This would be a "tunnel inside a tunnel" and could be routed through the cloud-server.